# How to specify which <p:messages> component to send message

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to update different  components depending on results in the bean. Right now I am using:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "test","test"));
```

And updating the proper  component with:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{Controller.method}" update="messageId"/>
<p:messages id="messageId"/>
```

Is there a different way to do it? From the bean, can I specify which message component to send the message to?

Comment: You can prepare message for specific component:  `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(componentId, msg)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Vasil said - you can bind the messages to ids (component doesn't necessarily need to exist for that id'

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("idspecified", new FacesMessage("Header", "body"));
```

And then in your xhtml use

```
<p:message for="idspecified" />
```

Comment: this method only works if the p:message tag is inside an area which is being ajax-ed